# how do I send a message with custom action hyperlink on it in telegram using Rasa

Tags: python, json, telegram, rasa

I want to display each element in a list as a text for the telegram users to click. When they click the text, it will trigger the select_element intent and send along the text as an entity for a custom action. However, this code does not work. Help please.

```
for element in subset_elements:
      hyperlink = f"[{element}](tg://bot_command?command=/select_element&element={element})"
      payload = f'/select_element{{"element": "{element}"}}'
      dispatcher.utter_message(text=hyperlink, payload=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for element in subset_elements:
    hyperlink = f"[{element}](tg://bot_command?command=select_element&element={element})"
    payload = f'/select_element{{"element": "{element}"}}'
    dispatcher.utter_message(text=hyperlink, custom=payload)
```